# ListView Item adding dynamically

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I want to add catnames in listview.but it show me run time error.this is my code and logcat.i am able to add static array but when i use dynamically it show mw an error.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //setContentView(R.layout.main);


    TextView attribute[];
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    try 
    {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/catdata.xml");

        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

    Cat_id = new TextView[sitesList.getCat_id().size()];
    Cat_Parentid = new TextView[sitesList.getCat_id().size()];
    Cat_Name = new TextView[sitesList.getCat_id().size()];
    Cat_Desc=new TextView[sitesList.getCat_id().size()];
    String mystr,newstr;

    for (int i = 0; i <sitesList.getCat_Name().size(); i++) 
    {
        catNames=new String[sitesList.getCat_Name().size()];

        Cat_Name[i] = new TextView(this);
        Cat_Name[i].setText("Cat_Name = "+sitesList.getCat_Name().get(i));
        catNames[i]=sitesList.getCat_Name().get(i);
        Log.v("catnames",catNames[i]);
        str[i]=sitesList.getCat_Desc().get(i);
            temp[i]=str[i];


        }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,catNames));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);


}
static final String[] PENS = new String[]{
    "MONT Blanc",
    "Gucci",
    "Parker",
    "Sailor",
    "Porsche Design",
    "Rotring",
    "Sheaffer",
    "Waterman"
   };
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String pen = o.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen ::" + " " + pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

My LOGCAT--

```
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-17 19:29:17.230: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2517):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a NullPointerException because adapter, which is an ArrayAdapter is not initialized. Call its constructor, initialize it correctly and this problem will be history. The runtime error occurs when you try to call a method of this (nonexistant) object. If you assign a value to adapter, the NullPointerException should not happen again with this object. You might have other bugs too, but our problem is the NullPointerException thrown when you call the method of an uninitialized object (which is a null pointer without initialization).